# Can't change native base tabs' height

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, native-base

Tab is working correctly. But I can't change the underline and the height of `<Tabs>` like the image below

[image]

I'm using Native-Base to handle tabs. But I can't think of any way to change its default height.

```
<Tabs initialPage={0}
  tabBarUnderlineStyle={styles.tabBarUnderlineStyle}
  style={{height:40}}
>
  <Tab 
    heading="Following"
    tabStyle={styles.tabStyle}
    activeTabStyle={styles.activeTabStyle}
    activeTextStyle={styles.activeTextStyle}
    textStyle={styles.textStyle}
  >
    <FeedScreen navigation={this.props.navigation}/>
  </Tab>
```

Should I use another navigation? native-base is terrible to customize.. :(

**UPDATE** as request, I'm sharing my style

```
  tabStyle : {
    // backgroundColor: theme.colors.navbar,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    width: 120,
    height: 40,
  },
  activeTabStyle: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    height: 40,
  },
  textStyle: {
    // color: 'white',
    color: "#968D8A"
  },
  activeTextStyle: {
    // color: 'white',
    color: theme.colors.navbar
  },
  tabBarUnderlineStyle: {
    backgroundColor: theme.colors.navbar,
    height: 2
  }
```

Comment: Can you please share your styles.

Comment: Sure I just did

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `tabContainerStyle` prop of `<Tabs/>` to adjust the height. Same way use `tabBarUnderlineStyle` prop to style the tab indicator.

```
<Tabs
      tabContainerStyle={{ height: 60 }}
      tabBarUnderlineStyle={{
        backgroundColor: "black",
        height: 5,
      }}
    />
```

Comment: it is working in normal component but not working in bottom drawable component